# Return the last argument of a function

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, parameter-passing

I'm stuck whilst trying to find the last element of a list:

The function:

```
function last(list) {

}
```

'list' can be an array, a string or a list of arguments. I have code for the occurrence of both an array and a string but am unsure how to return the last argument. This is what I have so far:

```
function last(list){
  if(typeof list === 'string') {
    return list.charAt(list.length - 1);
  }
  if(typeof list === 'object') {
    return list[list.length - 1];
  }
  if(typeof list === '...') {
    .....
  }
}
```

Help a brother out!

Thanks.

Comment: Define "List of arguments". Do you mean that `last` might be passed more than one argument or that the value of `list` might be an [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)?

Comment: *"'list' can be an array, a string or a list of arguments"* JavaScript has no intrinsic concept of a "list" other than an array or iterable. What do you mean by "list of arguments"? Also note that your check for an array is almost certainly incorrect; you probably want `if (Array.isArray(list))` (although that will be false for a *typed* array).

Comment: This could mostly be generalised to `if (list.hasOwnProperty('length')) return list[list.length - 1]`. For anything else which does not have a `length` property "last" is rather undefined to begin with.

Comment: Sorry I have been unclear, this would be an example of multiple arguments being passed:

(last(1,"b",3,"d",5))

Comment: @georgeperry Why would you ever to that? It's clear that `5` is the last value there.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's an assignment, and I've been searching for a solution for ages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get an array-like object containing all the arguments passed to a function (unless it is an arrow function) using `arguments`.

```
if (arguments.length > 1) {
    var what_I_care_about = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
}
```